# Chinese chars not displayed properly when Puppet starts Tomcat, works when manually started

Tags: java, tomcat, character-encoding, puppet, file-encodings

So here's a fun one...

We have a file upload through Fatwire that stores files on a Unix file system.  Fatwire uses Tomcat under the covers.

A Puppet agent handles our jar deployment and restart.

When uploading an image file that has Chinese chars in its filename, the file stored on the file system is displaying the dreaded ??? instead of the proper characters.

When we use the same jar file that Puppet deployed but simply restart manually, it works perfectly.

I already have -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 set in the JAVA_OPTS and CATALINA_OPTS settings.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is some environment variable.

You can probably test this as follows:

- Stop the java process from a shell
- Do a Puppet run from that shell

If the chinese chars show, it is pretty likely that it is an environment variable.

Comment: Probably the `LANG` variable or one of the `LC_*` variables.

Comment: We determined that puppet was running under a different JVM and the environment variables weren't properly set for it.